# Simplify multiple if statements with definition python

Tags: python, python-3.x

`locationx`, `locationx`, `x`, `y` and `airports` are arrays.

```
if locationx[plane] == x[0] and locationy[plane] == y[0]:
    planelocation[plane] = airports[0]
if locationx[plane] == x[1] and locationy[plane] == y[1]:
    planelocation[plane] = airports[1]
```

As you can see, the code above is doing the same thing twice. Is there any way this could be simplified e.g. be able to make a definition to detect if `locationx` and `locationy` `==` `x[n]` and `y[n]`?

Comment: Just use `and`.

Comment: Sharing what there is in the variables `locationx`, `locationy`, `airports` and `planelocation` will give some sens of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Place one of the 2 conditionals in a *for* loop (and replace the index number by the looping variable). Also make sure it's syntactically correct: (`and if` *->* `and`).

Comment: you could assign `locationx[plane]`, `locationy[plane]` to variables with shorter names to make code shorter. And Python will not have to search in list two times.

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(locationx); print(locationy); print(x); print(y)`

Comment: `if (locationx[plane], locationy[plane]) == (x[0], y[0]): ...` You can try writing the if statements like this to make the code look a little cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `x`, `y`, `airplanes` has more then two items so it is good to use `zip()` to group them and then use in comparition. Frankly, you could keep these information together in one list or dictionary.

I also assume that you search first matching data so you can use `break` to skip other

I also assing location to shorter variables so code is shorter and Python doesn't have to search the same element on list many times.

```
px = locationx[plane]
py = locationy[plane]

for temp_x, temp_y, temp_airports in zip(x, y, airports): 
    if px == temp_x and py == temp_y:
         planelocation[plane] = temp_airports
         break # don't check others
```

I couldn't find better names for variables so I used prefix `temp_`

---

As you suggest you can use `n` for this

```
px = locationx[plane]
py = locationy[plane]

for n in range(2):
    if px == x[n] and py == y[n]:
         planelocation[plane] = airports[n]
         break # don't check others
```

If you have more elements to check then you can use `range(len(airports))` which usually is not prefered because you can replace it with `zip()` or other more readable method.

```
for n in range(len(airports)):
    if px == x[n] and py == y[n]:
         planelocation[plane] = airports[n]
         break # don't check others
```

I assumed that `x`, `y`, `airplanes` has the same number of elements and I can use `len(airports)` instead of `len(x)` or `len(y)`